# Error: native-image -H:Name=$url -cp .:BOOT-INF/classes:`find BOOT-INF/lib | tr '\n' ':'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

run with

- springBoot=3.1.0
- springCloud=2022.0.3
- graalvmNative=0.9.22 ,

with these dependencies

```
dependencies {    
 //gateway     
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")     
  implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway")     
  implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery")     
  implementation("com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine") 
}
```

implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
ues gradle nativeComplie is ok
use native-image -H:Name=$url -cp .:BOOT-INF/classes:`find BOOT-INF/lib | tr '\n' ':' error
how to resolve this problem

```
Fatal error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error encountered while parsing io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.<init>(io.netty.channel.Channel, java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel, int)
Parsing context:
   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel.<init>(AbstractNioChannel.java:80)
   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel.<init>(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:42)

        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.parsingError(AnalysisError.java:153)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createFlowsGraph(MethodTypeFlow.java:104)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureFlowsGraphCreated(MethodTypeFlow.java:83)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.getOrCreateMethodFlowsGraph(MethodTypeFlow.java:65)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.typestate.DefaultSpecialInvokeTypeFlow.onObservedUpdate(DefaultSpecialInvokeTypeFlow.java:61)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.update(TypeFlow.java:562)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis$1.run(PointsToAnalysis.java:488)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.executeCommand(CompletionExecutor.java:193)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$executeService$0(CompletionExecutor.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.classinitialization.ClassInitializationFeature.checkImageHeapInstance(ClassInitializationFeature.java:132)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.replaceObject(AnalysisUniverse.java:595)
```